# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'click'

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I want click on next li item from current active item. Which li is active, its a tag contain active class.

So first of all, I get active a tag and it's parent li. Now I get index of li in ul . Then add 1 in its value and get next a tag and fire click event on it.

My code is working fine in IE and Firefox, but in Chrome I get following exception.

> "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'click'"

please suggests me usable link or sample code or correction in my code.

My html code is :-

```
    <nav class="cycle-nav-container" role="navigation">         
   <ul class="list-b" id="cycle-1-nav">
            <li class="hitmo"><a href="http://hitmo-studio.com/#hitmo">Hitmo</a></li>
            <li class="fastpr"><a href="#" class="active">FastPr</a></li>
            <li class="thinkmedia"><a href="http://hitmo-studio.com/#thinkmedia">Thinkmedia</a></li>
            <li class="arkana"><a href="http://hitmo-studio.com/#arkana">Arkana</a></li>
            <li class="bioway"><a href="http://hitmo-studio.com/#bioway">Bioway</a></li>
            <li class="nana"><a href="http://hitmo-studio.com/#nana">Nanaform</a></li>
            <li class="akademia"><a href="http://hitmo-studio.com/#akademia">Social Media Academy</a></li>
        </ul>
  </nav>
```

My Javascript code is:-

```
  var navIndex = $('.cycle-nav-container .list-b .active').parent();
    var nextIndex = $("ul.list-b li").index(navIndex) + 1;
    var par = $("ul.list-b");
    if(nextIndex>=par[0].children.length)
    nextIndex=0;
    var nextElement = par[0].children[nextIndex];
    var navIndex12 = nextElement.children[0];
   navIndex12.click();
```

Comment: `navIndex12` is not a jQuery object, but a simple DOM element, so it doesn't have a method `click`

Comment: that work now , but please explain me why it is work on IE& Firefox or give me details explanation link of this thing.

Comment: For FF at least: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To invoke the click handler for a DOM element, IE defines a click method which basically fires the click event . Firefox implemented it from FF 5+.

However Chrome still uses the standard W3C defined dispatchEvent for programatically firing the event.

Or it could also be that the navindex12 object returned could be a DOMTextElement. Try alerting the navindex12.nodeType

To conclude , you should try to gracefully check for browser and element constraints before calling the click method.